# Looping through variable containing Ansible host group in delegate_to statement

Tags: ansible

I have a variable in my Ansible plan that I am setting like so -

```
 pre_tasks:

  - name: Hosts
    debug:
      msg: "dev_web"
    register: web_server_group
```

In my hosts file I have an entry like this -

```
[dev_web]
1.1.1.6
```

In my Ansible plan,  I have a `delegate_to` command that is trying to run on the host's that are inside of that dev_web group by using the `web_server_group` variable that is defined to the group name.

```
- name: Folder creation
  file:
    path: /tmp/dummy
    owner: apache
    group: apache
    mode: 0770
    state: directory
  delegate_to: "{{ web_server_group }}"
```

That gives me this error -

```
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname web_server_group: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}
```

Is there a way to get the the delegate_to command to populate with the hosts that are supposed to be in the web_server_group variable that I set as a pre-task?

I tried replacing the `delegate_to` command with this -

```
  delegate_to: '{{ item }}'
  with_items: "{{ groups['web_server_group'] }}"
```

But I get this error -

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'web_server_group'"}
```

Is there another way I could accomplish this or something similar to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Specifically, I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with this:

```
- name: Hosts
  debug:
    msg: "dev_web"
  register: web_server_group
```

That will create a variable named `web_server_group` with the following content:

```
{
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": false, 
    "msg": "dev_web"
}
```

You *already* have a group named `dev_web` that would seem to contain exactly the hosts you're trying to target.

If you want to run a task on a particular group of hosts, just create a play targeting that group.  For example:

```
- hosts: dev_web
  tasks:
    - name: Folder creation
      file:
        path: /tmp/dummy
        owner: apache
        group: apache
        mode: 0770
        state: directory
```

This would create the `/tmp/dummy` directory on all hosts in your `dev_web` group. There's not really any reason to use delegation here.

Comment: Yeah, I think I just figured it out by making the debug message `msg: "{{ groups['dev_web'] }}"`, which removes what you are talking about too since it then gives me `1.1.1.6` like I want.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You really don't need that `debug` task at all, nor the variable you're creating.

Comment: The issue I was having was because we have different environments, (Dev, Stage, Prod), so I had a `when` statement underneath to determine the servers to run on based on whether the user passed in dev, stage, or prod. I got it working thanks to your tip, and just set the host to `host: {{ env }}_web`.  Thanks again for the help.